# Solve limit (trig) without l'Hopitals rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I had this question for math
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{ax^2}}{\sin{bx^2}}
$$

So I used squeeze theorem and got $-1<1/(\sin{bx^2})<1$
and I multiplied by $\sin{ax^2}$ and got $-\sin{ax^2}< \sin{ax^2}/\sin{bx^2}< \sin{ax^2}$

Which then equals $0 < \lim_{x\to 0}\sin{ax^2}/\sin{bx^2}<0$
and the answer I got is $0$, 
but the answer is supposed to be $a/b$

Where did I go wrong and how can you solve this without using l'Hôpital's rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $(\sin x)/x$:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(ax^2)}{\sin(bx^2)}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(ax^2)}{ax^2}\frac{bx^2}{\sin(bx^2)}\frac{a}{b}
$$

---

Where did you go wrong? The inequality $-1<1/\sin(bx^2)<1$ is false for all $x$: if $0<\sin(bx^2)<1,$ then $1/\sin(bx^2)>1$; if $-1<\sin(bx^2)<0,$ then $1/\sin(bx^2)<-1$.

Comment: wait... can you explain how that works, like you basically multiplied it by bx^2/ax^2, and it is still undefined when you sub in 0, thanks

Comment: @SpongebobSquareroot-pants Yes, but you surely know that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: @SpongebobSquareroot-pants When taking a limit, the point is not implicated.  Therefore, there was no division by $0$.

Comment: isn't that basically still Hospital? How do you show $\frac{sin\left(x\right)}{x}\stackrel{x\rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow} 1$?

Comment: @Max That's a basic limit, used for finding the derivative of sine and cosine.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it is basic. But still: Don't you have to consider the power series for $\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}$ and estimate it to get that result?

Comment: @Max When you have “compute without l'Hôpital” exercises, some basic limits are to be considered known, otherwise you'd go round in circles.

Comment: then it's in the opinion of the corrector... I personally would not accept it :-) but that's an opinion. It should be easy enuff by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Comment: @Max Conversely, I consider most of the “compute without l'Hôpital” exercises dull and almost useless. Why shouldn't one use a well known and powerful method, provided it's applicable and apt to the point?

Comment: @Max: The limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at zero is basic geometry. All you need is the area of the unit circle, the way to find the area of a triangle, and the fact that $\cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 1$. See https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/afenyes/seeing/sinc.pdf for a sketch.

Comment: depends... on the definition of "usefull" xD I think the "use" here could be to force people to get famillar with more technical arguments. if that's not nescessairy, then i admit "uselessness".

Comment: @egreg: Because those basic limits don't have to just "be considered known"; see my comment to Max. Doing things without l'Hôpital's rule forces you to learn the fundamentals, instead of relying on sophisticated machinery. It is, perhaps, the mathematical equivalent of learning how to drive a car with a stick shift, which you may or may not also consider dull and almost useless.

Comment: @Max: Arguments without l'Hospital's rule are often *less* technical. That's certainly true in this case (see my previous comment to you).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to "squeeze" the ratio is to use the inequalities

$$\left|x\cos x\right|\le\left|\sin x\right|\le \left|x\right|$$

Then, we have

$$\left|\frac{ax^2\cos (ax^2)}{bx^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{\sin(ax^2)}{\sin(bx^2)}\right|\le\left|\frac{ax^2}{bx^2\cos(bx^2)}\right|$$

In the limit as $x\to 0$, we have then that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ax^2\cos (ax^2)}{bx^2}=\frac ab$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ax^2}{bx^2\cos(bx^2)}=\frac ab$$

Thus, by the squeeze theorem,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax^2)}{\sin(bx^2)}=\frac ab$$

Comment: Thanks for providing such a nice alternate solution. +1

Comment: @Shailesh You're welcome! My pleasure.